# Insert Trigger not working SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have audit table to maintain all actions takes in database. I have TestDetails  table and create INSERT, UPDATE triggers on it. Update trigger is working fine in windows7 and INSERT trigger is not working with windows7. But when I testing insert trigger in windows 8,10 its working well. I have included the query as following :

```
 CREATE TABLE TestDetails (
        ID           INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                                  UNIQUE
                                  NOT NULL,
        Type  VARCHAR (50),
       CreatedDate DATETIME, ModifiedDate DATETIME, CreatedBy INT, ModifiedBy INT
    );
    CREATE TABLE Audit (
        TableName VARCHAR (50),
        ID        INT (10),
        Type      VARCHAR (30),
        CDT       DATETIME,
        Changeset TEXT (800) 
    );

    INSERT TRIGGER :
    CREATE TRIGGER TRGINS_TestDetails AFTER INSERT ON TestDetails FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN  INSERT INTO Audit(TableName,ID,Type,CDT,ChangeSet) VALUES('TestDetails', new.ID, 'INSERT',DATETIME('NOW'), 
    '<ChangeSet>' || 
    '<Id><New>' || new.Id || '</New>' || 
    '<Type><New>' || new.Type || '</New>' ||
'<CreatedDate><New>' || new.CreatedDate || '</New>' ||  
'<CreatedBy><New>' || new.CreatedBy || '</New>' || 
'<ModifiedDate><New>' || new.ModifiedDate || '</New>' ||  
'<ModifiedBy><New>' || new.ModifiedBy || '</New>' || 
     || '</ChangeSet>'); END


    UPDATE TRIGGER :
    CREATE TRIGGER [TRGUPD_TestDetails ]
             AFTER UPDATE
                ON TestDetails
    BEGIN INSERT INTO Audit ( TableName, ID,Type, CDT, ChangeSet )
                               VALUES ('TestDetails', new.ID,'UPDATE',DATETIME('NOW'),
                                   '<ChangeSet>' || CASE WHEN old.Id <> new.Id THEN '<Id><Old>' || old.Id || '</Old><New>' || new.Id || '</New>' ELSE '' END || CASE WHEN old.Type <> new.Type THEN '<Type><Old>' || old.Type || '</Old><New>' || new.Type || '</New>' ELSE '' END || 
CASE WHEN old.CreatedDate <> new.CreatedDate THEN '<CreatedDate><Old>' || old.CreatedDate || '</Old><New>' || new.CreatedDate || '</New>' ELSE '' END || 
 CASE WHEN old.ModifiedDate <> new.ModifiedDate THEN '<ModifiedDate><Old>' || old.ModifiedDate || '</Old><New>' || new.ModifiedDate || '</New>' ELSE '' END || 
 CASE WHEN old.CreatedBy <> new.CreatedBy THEN '<CreatedBy><Old>' || old.CreatedBy || '</Old><New>' || new.CreatedBy || '</New>' ELSE '' END || 
 CASE WHEN old.ModifiedBy <> new.ModifiedBy THEN '<ModifiedBy><Old>' || old.ModifiedBy || '</Old><New>' || new.ModifiedBy || '</New>' ELSE '' END ||
'</ChangeSet>'  );END;

Audit : 
TableName      ID       Type    CDT                      ChangeSet
TestDetails 1   INSERT  2016-10-12 09:03:00 NULL
TestDetails 1   UPDATE  2016-10-12 09:05:32 <ChangeSet><Type><Old>Type1</Old><New>Type11</New></ChangeSet>

The actual value for Changeset in windows8,10 is : <ChangeSet><ID><New>1</New><Type><New>Type1</New></ChangeSet>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Runs OK in Sqlitebrowser on Win7. Check your code on win7 installation.

Comment: @Serg I tried in win7 not working..

Comment: What is your Sqlite tool?

Comment: SQLiteStudio v3.1.0.. It is the problem with my sqlite installation?

Comment: What is the exact INSERT statement that you tried to use?

Comment: INSERT INTO TestDetails ( Type)  VALUES ( 'Type1');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The prblem is, while insert we didn't maintain ModifiedDate,Modified By. So, in trigger we need not maintain that fields. I changed my trigger as following:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER TRGINS_TestDetails AFTER INSERT ON TestDetails FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN  INSERT INTO Audit(TableName,ID,Type,CDT,ChangeSet) VALUES('TestDetails', new.ID, 'INSERT',DATETIME('NOW'), 
    '<ChangeSet>' || 
    '<Id><New>' || new.Id || '</New>' || 
    '<Type><New>' || new.Type || '</New>' ||
'<CreatedDate><New>' || new.CreatedDate || '</New>' ||  
'<CreatedBy><New>' || new.CreatedBy || '</New>'  
     || '</ChangeSet>'); END
```

Now its working... Thank you guys..